# Sending & Reading using JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, json

My Android Application Reads JSON Data from PHP File according to username and password Sent from Application also as JSON.
What I have reached for now that I can Only Read by specifying the username and password, No Sending for username and password from App happens..
My question is, Is it possible to Read and Also POST Using JSONParse ??
 
Please Take a look at the JSONParse Method I've Added a part that's commented because it's not working "Is it possible to Send Username and Password along with Reading status from Database Using JSON"

**JSONParse**

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
             private ProgressDialog pDialog;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(fishtank.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            /*Temp
                SharedPreferences settings =  getSharedPreferences("mySettings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 us = settings.getString("storedWifiUser", "");
                    ps = settings.getString("storedWifiPass", "");
                 try {
                     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 
                     json.put("user", us); 
                     json.put("pass", ps);

                     postData(json);


                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();}  Temp */
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();   
                // Getting JSON from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
                return json;
            }

            public void postData(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                try { 
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                    List<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);    
                    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json.toString()));
                    //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");  
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    Log.i("JSON Response : ",json.toString().trim());
                    if(response != null) {
                        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
                        //input stream is response that can be shown back on android
                    }

                }catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
            //Temp
             @Override

             protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 try {
                    // Log.i("JSON Response : ",json.toString().trim());
                    // Log.i("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());

                    // System.out.println("JSON Response : "+json.toString().trim());
                     JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject("status");
                     String tog1="";
                     String tog2="";
                     String tog3="";
                     if(c.has("fil"))

                            tog1 = c.getString("fil");

                        if(c.has("HEA"))
                         tog2 = c.getString("HEA");

                        if(c.has("LED"))
                            tog3 = c.getString("LED");

                        Log.i("JSON Response : ",json.toString().trim());
                                        if(tog1.equals("ON"))
                                        {   toggle1.setChecked(true);}
                                        else{ toggle1.setChecked(false);}
                                             if(tog2.equals("ON"))
                                             {   toggle2.setChecked(true);}
                                             else{   toggle2.setChecked(false);}
                                             if(tog3.equals("ON"))
                                             {    toggle3.setChecked(true);}
                                             else{toggle3.setChecked(false);}

                             } catch (JSONException e) {
                                 e.printStackTrace();
                             }

             }






        }//End Json
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","pet_home");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// if(isset($_POST['json'])){
    //    $json=$_POST['json'];
    //    $data2=json_decode($json,TRUE);
    //    $u=$data2->{'user'};
   //     $p=$data2->{'pass'};
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='osama' AND password='123'");
            $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
//$row_cnt=1;
             if($row_cnt>0){     
                 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
                $data = array('success'=>true, 'error'=>'',  'status'=>array("fil" => $row['filter_st'], "HEA"=> $row['heat_st'], "LED" =>$row['led_st'])); 
             }else{
                $data = array('success'=>false, 'error' => 'No records found');
             }               

   //  }else{
    //     $data = array('success'=>false, 'error' => 'No POST value from Android App');
  //   }

     echo json_encode($data);

mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use that for save to database

```
nameValuePairs2 = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
    nameValuePairs2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
 try{
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(mainurl+"registration.php");
                 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);
             //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response " + the_string_response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //   System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
             }
```

Comment: I don't want to save them , i just want to send username and password along side Reading status

Comment: JSON data as Object in the PHP file

Comment: post ur php file output

Comment: `{"success":true,"error":"","status":{"fil":"ON","HEA":"ON","LED":"ON"}}`

Comment: json format like this {"countrylist":[{"id":"241","country":" india"}]}        use object in that countrylist